# Python "with" statement but no "as"

Tags: python, kivy, with-statement

I'm used to using the python "with" statement but I'm playing with Kivy and noticed some code like this:

```
with self.canvas:
    Color(1., 1., 0)
    Rectangle(size=(50, 50))
```

Example from [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html)

There's no "as" portion of the "with" statement...

How do Color and Rectangle know what to act on?

Comment: Perhaps a global variable is introduced? I imagine that you could look up the source code of `self.canvas.__enter__` and `self.canvas.__exit__` to find out what it's doing.

Comment: The important line is [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L56), automatically checking for an active canvas that is set by the `with` statement [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L537).